# ETH1 balances transition to ETH2

Tags: transactions, blockchain, sharding, state

Can someone please explain how do the ETH1 balances become ETH2 if they don't move on-chain? How does eth1 become a shard?
Is ETH2 an airdrop of eth1 balances?

Answer (score 0):

ETH1 is a blockchain secured by Proof Of Work.
ETH2 is a blockchain secured by Proof Of Stake.

Balance on ETH1 are reported on ETH2 so you have nothing to do, if you have 1 ETH on precedent network you will have 1 ETH on the newest.

But just as Bitcoin/Bitcoin cash, there is a risk that miners support a hard fork so you will end up with 1 ETH on PoS chain and 1 ETH on PoW chain legacy.

ETH1 does not become a shard, it becomes ETH2.

ETH2 is not technically an airdrop, your balance will be inchanged.

Comment: BItcoin Cash was an airdrop of Bitcoin.
If miners remove the iceage, how is ETH2 not an airdrop of ETH1?